# Не изменяется шаблон продукта в Prestashop 1.7.6.8

Tags: prestashop

Появилась необходимость немного изменить шаблон карточки товара в Prestashop. В файлах используемой темы я нашел файл шаблона product.tpl. Изменил его. Сохранил. Но на сайте изменения не отображаются. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказывается просто. Нужно в админке перейти в Расширенные настройки -> Производительность
И в блоке Smarty выбрать перекомпиляцию шаблонов если файлы были изменены.